# Finding base of $\mathbb{R}^3 / U$ (U being a known subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

If $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the vectors $\{(2,0,-1),(1,2,0),(0,4,1)\}$, how can I find the basis for $\mathbb{R}^3 / U$?

I'm having trouble understanding how one can define a basis for *all the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$* which doesn't span specifically the vectors in $U$. I think it'd be possible to find some cartesian coordinates for $U$ and then replace the $=$ sign for $\ne$, but that doesn't seem to help much. So far, I've found that the three vectors that span $U$ aren't linearly independent, but they can be used to find the basis $\{(1,2,0),(0,4,1)\}$. Therefore, one can get the parametric equations of $U$, and then its cartesian equation: $2x-y+4z=0$.

Can someone hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$? I ask this because the set of all vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$ but not in $U$ is not a subspace, and thus does not have a basis.

Comment: What does the slash mean in $\mathbb{R}^3/U$? Is it a quotient space?

Comment: Since we haven't studied that in class, I'm assuming $\mathbb{R}^3 / U$ means every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ except for the ones contained in the plane that is $U$.

Comment: And how did you define a basis for something which is NOT a vector space in class? ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** You can find a vector $v_3$ such that $\{(1,2,0),(0,4,1), v_3\}$ is a Basis in $\mathbb R^3$. Then you can easily argue that $\{ v_3+U \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^3/U$.

This can be done in various ways: wither finding a basis among the vectors $\{(1,2,0),(0,4,1), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ which contains the first two vectors, by G-S, or by simply taking 
$$v_3=(1,2,0) \times (0,4,1)$$

Comment: Am I understanding what $\mathbb{R}^3 / U$ right? I think it means every vector contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$, except those contained in the plane that is $U$. Is that right? Or am I missing the actual meaning of $\mathbb{R}^3 / U$?

Comment: @Manuel I misunderstood your question at first, but no, actually $\Bbb{R}^3/U$ is [the quotient space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)), which is something very different.

Comment: @Manuel $\mathbb R^3$ removed a plane is NOT a vector space  hos can you find a basis for such a thing?